# IntelliJ directories error class not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm fairly new to IntelliJ and I have tried making a hello world program in some other directory other than `~/IdeaProject`. When I did so although my code is correct it gives me `ClassNotFoundException`. But when I copy the files into `~/IdeaProject` and open the project from that directory, I can run it just fine and it isn't from my code since I tried different ones and I already uninstalled and installed IntelliJ and still got the same result anybody can tell me why?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update: I can run my codes fine in all directories except a directory called: `/Course Material/Week 2/Web Server: Reflection/`
I can also run my program from command line in that directory and it works fine I suppose the problem is with IntelliJ.

```
 ~/U/S/I/C/W/W/untitled folder> ls
out/                 src/                 untitled folder.iml
 ~/U/S/I/C/W/W/untitled folder> 
cd src/com/company/
 ~/U/S/I/C/W/W/u/s/c/company> ls
Main.java
 ~/U/S/I/C/W/W/u/s/c/company> javac 
Main.java 
 ~/U/S/I/C/W/W/u/s/c/company> cd ../..
 ~/U/S/I/C/W/W/u/src [1]> java 
com.company.Main
write your code here
```

Does anybody have any idea why?

[simple program in the stated directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcXIy.png)

[same program  in the relative path ../](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BG6n.png)

Comment: Depends on a lot of things, for example your project structure, project configuration, etc.. Posting a picture of your project's tree might help. For example are your classes under `src/main/java`?

Comment: I added the screen shot to the post. and yes i only have only class which is in src/main/java

Comment: what do you have in your out folder ? You should have the .class file. And you souhld remove the Main.class file in the src folder. ".java" files are source code files, ".class" are the executable ones.

Comment: I updated the screen shots for better understanding of my problem and thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @fego I also added the out folder content in the updated Screenshots

Comment: @GhostCat I wanted to show my directories and output and also code so thats why I used screenshots & I'll try to avoid screenshot as much as I can and the package statement wasn't the problem since the java file was moved from the package directory and I also changed the screenshots where the file is in the package directory and package statement isn't commented out and I still get the same result

Comment: @GhostCat I'm not trying to change the way it works i just wanna understand why does intelliJ have a problem with this directory.

Comment: But you are not giving us the details necessary to help you. `I can also run my program from command line in that directory and it works fine I suppose the problem is with IntelliJ.` How did you do that? Exactly?

Comment: Guessing, I am wondering if that `:` in the path creates a problem for this or that tool.

Comment: But as said, we lack the detail to really help. See [mcve]. You *somehow* describing what you did isnt sufficient here. Details really matter. Worst case, give a step by step description of what you tried. But then, such kind of "help" is really hard. A real person looking at your screen and being able to run this or that command might be able to figure the issue in a few seconds. But remember: we only have what you tell us about. So ... rather look around, arent there any peers or tutors that you can *talk* with?

Comment: @GhostCat I added how i run the program using terminal as you requested.
I guess you're right the problem might be that there is a slash in the file name that IntelliJ has replaced with ':' which is really strange the actual file name is "Web Server/Reflection"

Comment: Well "/" is the directory separator on Mac Os. You cant use the "/" as part of a filename.

Comment: If you provide the command runned by intellij it could help (first line in the console), in order to check the classpath.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for the help the problem was the slash in the filename; which when I renamed the errors went away thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a '/' (slash) in my file name which intelliJ replaced with ':' when I changed the slash the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

Your project is not properly initialized and IntelliJ sees the classes as just plain files in ordinary folders and not as a project which classes interact with each other.

Start by creating a new project through `File → New → Project`, define your project in a way that suits your needs and after the setup is complete copy your classes under `src/main/java`. This is default, but basically your main classes need to be under a folder which is marked as "Sources Root". Afterwards you can also doublecheck if your SDK is configured properly (`File → Project Structure → SDKs`) and if you're using the correct language level in your project(`File → Project Structure → Modules → Language Level`).